# Using setState() for update view with data from API - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS. In my current project i'm populating data to HTML table from Mongo database and i have one column with checkbox(dynamically created based on db values) for select default profile(see below image). When checking one profile, particular profile in db will update with flag **true** and others are **false**

[image: Profiles table]

On checkbox click it will call API to update db flag. After update db i needs call a API to get data from same collection and update table. And i'm using following code.

I'm trying to use **setState** for render new data without refreshing page. I think i'm using **setState** without better understanding and i need to clear that. My questions are whats wrong with below code and is the any better way to achieve this scenario other than using **setState** ?

**Profiles.jsx - render()**

```
render() {
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <div>
      <table className="table">
        <thead className="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Create Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Last Updated Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Default Profile</th>
            <th scope="col">Update</th>
            <th scope="col">Delete</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.state.profilesData.map(prof => (
            <tr key={prof._id}>
              <th scope="row">{prof._id}</th>
              <td>{prof.createdDate}</td>
              <td>{prof.lastUpdatedDate}</td>
              <td align="center">
                {prof.defaultProfile === true ? (
                  <input
                    name="defaultProfileCheck"
                    type="checkbox"
                    aria-label="Checkbox for following text input"
                    onChange={() => this.toggleDefault(prof._id)}
                    defaultChecked
                  />
                ) : (
                  <input
                    name="defaultProfileCheck"
                    type="checkbox"
                    aria-label="Checkbox for following text input"
                    onChange={() => this.toggleDefault(prof._id)}
                  />
                )}
              </td>
              <td>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-warning">
                  Update
                </button>
              </td>
              <td>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger">
                  Delete
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

}

**toggleDefault - onChange**

```
state = {
  profilesData: []
};

async componentDidMount() {
const profiles = await getUserProfiles();  //Service Call
this.setState({ profilesData: profiles.data }); }

async toggleDefault(_id) {
if (window.confirm("Are you sure?")) {
  try {
    await setDefaultProfile(_id); //Service Call
  } catch (ex) {
    if (ex.response && ex.response.status === 404) toast.error(ex.message);
  }
  //toast.success("Done.");
  const profiles = await getUserProfiles(); //Service call for get updated data
  this.setState({ profilesData: profiles.data }); //Trying to setState for update view
} else {

}
}
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is exactly the usecase for ComponentDidUpdate.

Please go here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate
There is an example, which I've included below that will help you to update the data as you wish to do.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)
```

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.props.userID !== prevProps.userID) {
    this.fetchData(this.props.userID);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. your answer helped me to solve my case. i use componentDidUpdate() as you said and change "defaultChecked" to checked={prof.defaultProfile}. thank you again.